# Conemu problems with vi, top and clear

Tags: conemu

The cygwin bash console only resets the cursor to the top of the screen, it does not clear the screen. vi does funny things with the cursor - hard to explain, but the cursor seems double wide when in vi. top output is mostly double-spaced, but sometimes single spaces.

When I use mintty I have none of these issues.

I've tried all kinds of settings in the last several hours, too many to list. Seems like I'm going backwards. I've got conemu working great on another computer, and I've tried replicating the setup but there must be something I'm missing.

What information can I provide to help solve these issues?

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/TableOfContents.html#cygwin-and-msys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem machine had an old version of Cygwin. Mintty received a [major upgrade in July 2015](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-07/msg00110.html). Numerous other packages have been upgraded also in the 2 years since I installed Cygwin in that machine. After upgrading Cygwin, the problems went away.

Answer (score 2):

I've someone else runs into this issue: you probably need to set `TERM=cygwin` in your `.bashrc`.